# How to Align D3.js X-axis Dates with Supplied Data

Tags: d3.js

I'm creating a time-based line chart and everything looks fine but I'm having difficulty with the x-axis tickmarks. As you can see http://jsfiddle.net/shubo/Yvupw/ the dates start at 2013-01-30 and ends at 2013-04-17 but the chart tick mark starts at 2013-2-3 and ends at 2013-4-14. What do I need to do so the first tickmark would show 2013-01-03 and the last one would show 2013-4-17?

```
var json = {
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "2013-04-17",
      "metric": 437792798
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-04-10",
      "metric": 437792998
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-04-03",
      "metric": 434633203
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-03-27",
      "metric": 431786310
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-03-20",
      "metric": 429614980
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-03-13",
      "metric": 427709519
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-03-06",
      "metric": 425894908
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-02-27",
      "metric": 423657524
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-02-20",
      "metric": 420392146
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-02-13",
      "metric": 417215035
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-02-06",
      "metric": 412433066
    },
    {
      "date": "2013-01-30",
      "metric": 408952856
    }
  ]
};

var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 110 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.metric); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = json.data;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
});

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.date - b.date;
});

x.domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date]);
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.metric; }));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

var format = d3.format(',');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [axis.tickValues([values])](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks) to control exactly which tick marks appear or use one of the one of the other tick settings.